# How to publish generic builds via python to an artifact repository?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, artifactory, continuous-deployment

I am looking for a flexible solution for uploading generic builds to an artifact repository (in my case it would be Artifactory but I would not mind if it would also support others, like Nexus)

[image]

Because I am **not** building java code adding maven to the process would only add some unneeded complexity to the game.

Still, the entire infrastructure already supports bash and python everywhere (including Windows) which makes me interested on finding something that involves those two.

I do know that I could code it myself, but now I am looking for a way to make it as easy and flexible as possible.

Gathering the metadata seems simple, only publishing it in the format required by the artefact repository seems to be the issue.

After discovering that the two existing Python packages related to Artifactory are kinda useless as both not being actively maintained, one being only usable as a query interface and the other two having serious bugs that prevent it use, I discovered something than seems to close that what I was looking: http://teamfruit.github.io/defend_against_fruit/

Still, it seems that was designed to deal only with python packages, not with generic builds.

Comment: As I wasn't able to find something useful for this case, I am currently working on something like this, so soon I will be able to provide an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Some points to consider:

1. Tools like Maven and [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) are capable of building [more than Java](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/standard_plugins.html#N11AFF) projects. Artifactory already integrates with them and this includes gathering the metadata and publishing it together with the build artifacts.
2. The Artifactory Jenkins plugin supports [generic](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin-ConfiguringGeneric%28Freestyle%29Builds) (freestyle) builds. You can use this integration to deploy whatever type of files you like.
3. You can create your own integration based on the Artifactory's open integration layer for CI build servers - [build-info](https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info). This is an open source project and all the implementations are also open sourced.
   The relevant Artifactory REST APIs are documented [here](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-BUILDS).

---

Disclaimer: I'm affiliated with Artifactory